# How does one prevent replication of the world map

Tags: bing-maps

I am using bing ajax map to display a map of the world.  However, the world map is relicated several times in the map window.  How do I ensure that the atlas is not replicated.

```
// Instantiate map, and show world view:
    var mapOptions = {credentials: "your cred here",
        zoom:  2,
        disableBirdseye: false,
        enableClickableLogo: false,
        fixedMapPosition: true,
        showCopyright: false,
        showScalebar: true,
        showDashboard: true,
        mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
        center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(45, 90)
    };
    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
```

Here is the html div that contains the map.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable the world wrap in the Bing Maps v7 AJAX control.